# How to retrieve data from a DatePickerDialog to an AlertDialog

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-alertdialog, datepickerdialog

I have a `MainFragment` from where a button creates an `AlertDialog` in there there are multiple fields and one of them is the date, in the date button I call an `DatePickerDialog` and select the date, so my question is : 
 How can I retrieve that date and set it on the `TextView` of the alert dialog on the`MainFragment`?

## This is on the AlertDialog on the main fragment:

```
public class FragmentInicio extends Fragment{
   String date;

  public void addDate(){

  View view = (LayoutInflater.from(getActivity())).inflate(R.layout.alert_dialog,null);

AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
alertDialog.setView(view);

final EditText date_EditText = view.findViewById(R.id.dateEditText);
final ImageButton dateButton= view.findViewById(R.id.tareaFechaButton);
dateButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        CalendarPickerFragment newFragment = new CalendarPickerFragment();
        newFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "DatePicker");

    }
});

date_EditText.setText(date);

alertDialog.setTitle("New Date");
alertDialog.setCancelable(true).setPositiveButton("Save", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
       //Some stuff
    }
});

alertDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        dialog.cancel();
    }
});
Dialog dialog = alertDialog.create();
dialog.show();

}

public static void displaydate(int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
    date = String.format("%02d", dayOfMonth) + "/" + String.format("%02d", monthOfYear + 1) + "/" +
            String.format("%02d", year);
    Log.d("DTAG", "date: "+date);
}
```

}

## This is on the CalendarPickerFragment

> Update

```
public class CalendarPickerFragment extends DialogFragment implements  DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {

    private CalendarPickerFragment.OnDateReceiveCallBack mListener;
    private Context context;

    public interface OnDateReceiveCallBack {
         void onDateReceive(int dd ,int mm, int yy);
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        this.context = context;

        try {
            mListener = (CalendarPickerFragment.OnDateReceiveCallBack) context;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException(context.toString() + " must implement OnDateSetListener");
        }
    }

    public CalendarPickerFragment(){
    }



    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        final Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        int year = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int month = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int day = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

        return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year, month, day);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker datePicker, int i, int i1, int i2) {
        Log.d(TAG, i + "/" + "/" + i1 + "/" + i2);
        mListener.onDateReceive(i,i1,i2);
    }
}
```

## MainActivity

```
public class MainActivty implements CalendarPickerFragment.OnDateReceiveCallBack{
@Override
    public void onDateReceive(int dd, int mm, int yy) {
        MainFragment.displaydate(dd,mm,yy);
    }
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50119457/how-to-change-the-text-of-a-running-alertdialog
two threads for same quest.. i answered you there https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50119457/how-to-change-the-text-of-a-running-alertdialog

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it either the ugly way getting your parent `Activity` from your `Fragment` using [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14354398/7427772) and then using setters to fill attributes from your parent `Activity`, or either using interfaces as [shown here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14439941/passing-data-between-fragments-to-activity).

## EDIT

Check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50119457/7427772).

Comment: The problem is I need the date to be set on the _AlertDialog_ that was open, if I pass the string is just going to add the text to the next time I open the _AlertDialog_

Comment: @AlfonsoBriceño Can't you use `setText()` method from `EditText` to modify it whenever you want to?

Comment: I used this method [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47740237/add-date-picker-fragment-inside-fragment)  to get the string from the CalendarPicker to the main fragment, but this stores the date on the string after creating the `EditText` on the `AlertDialog` so the `EditText` gets the string that was set before the creation of the `AlertDialog`. Its a silly problem but I am not that good at Java

Comment: Any way to do it will be highly appreciated!

Comment: @AlfonsoBriceño have you tried to use `setText()` function as I mentioned before?

Comment: Yes I did, but the setText is runned when I create the Dialog, therefore it puts the date String before I select the date, and is not updated when I select the date. Do you get my dilemma?

Comment: @AlfonsoBriceño I don't get it : you're displaying to the user something so that he can pick a date, and at the same time you're diplaying him a Dialog box?

Comment: Yes I am displaying him a AlertDialog where there are multiple fields in one of them there is a button and a Edit Text, when he presses the button a CalendarPicker shows up. I would like to set the selected date on the Edit Text

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170160/discussion-between-nofix-and-alfonso-briceno).