# How to change the text of a running AlertDialog

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-alertdialog

How do you change the current string of a text on a `AlertDialog` after you click a button that selects a date from a CalendarPickerFragment.

**This the AlertDialog**

```
    public class FragmentInicio extends Fragment{
       private static String date;

        public void addDate(){

        View view = (LayoutInflater.from(getActivity())).inflate(R.layout.alert_dialog,null);

      AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
      alertDialog.setView(view);

      final TextView date_Text = view.findViewById(R.id.dateEditText);
      final ImageButton dateButton= view.findViewById(R.id.tareaFechaButton);
      dateButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            CalendarPickerFragment newFragment = new CalendarPickerFragment();
            newFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "DatePicker");

        }
    });

      date_Text.setText(date);

      alertDialog.setTitle("New Date");
      alertDialog.setCancelable(true).setPositiveButton("Save", new 
  DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
           //Some stuff
        }
    });

    alertDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new 
   DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.cancel();
        }
    });
  Dialog dialog = alertDialog.create();
dialog.show();

}

public static void displaydate(int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
    date = String.format("%02d", dayOfMonth) + "/" + String.format("%02d", monthOfYear + 1) + "/" +
            String.format("%02d", year);
    Log.d("DTAG", "date: "+date);
}
```

**CalendarPickerFragment**

```
public class CalendarPickerFragment extends DialogFragment implements  DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {

private CalendarPickerFragment.OnDateReceiveCallBack mListener;
private Context context;

public interface OnDateReceiveCallBack {
    public void onDateReceive(int dd ,int mm, int yy);
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    this.context = context;

    try {
        mListener = (CalendarPickerFragment.OnDateReceiveCallBack) context;
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        throw new ClassCastException(context.toString() + " must implement OnDateSetListener");
    }
}

public CalendarPickerFragment(){
}



@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    final Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    int year = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    int month = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    int day = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

    return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year, month, day);
}

@Override
public void onDateSet(DatePicker datePicker, int i, int i1, int i2) {
    Log.d(TAG, i + "/" + "/" + i1 + "/" + i2);
    mListener.onDateReceive(i,i1,i2);
}
```

Comment: if you can provide your alert_dialog xml file too

Comment: in date picker there is an interface called onDateSelectedListner. which returns the date in its call back function onDateSet this is the method where you can change the edit text value

Comment: @AdeelTurk Could you explain me how? I already tried that way

Comment: @AlfonsoBriceño can you share CalendarPickerFragment code then i can tell you the exact answer

Comment: and what i get from your question is that you wanna show the date selected or any other text in edittext on date selection..

Comment: @AdeelTurk Okay I added it to the main post and yes thats correct I want to show the selected date in the Edit Text of the AlertDialog

Comment: Are you starting a `DialogFragment` from an `AlertDialog`? And you want to use the date from the "CalendarPickerFragment"  and insert it in the `EditText` of your `AlertDialog`? What happens when you start the "CalendarPickerFragment"  does the `AlertDialog` stay available after the date is selected from the "CalendarPickerFragment" ?

Comment: @Barns Yes it stays available but without the date, the date is set when I open the dialog again. My problem is that I want to set the date on the current Alert Dialog

Comment: I can't really see your user scenario, but wouldn't it be easier just to create a `DialogFragment` with the calendar and `EditText` and just start that?  Why the detour over an `AlertDialog` ?? Your Custom `AlertDialog` appears to have only the two views `Button` and `EditText`.

Comment: @Barns What you cant see? Is a relatively simple problem I think. But Im going to take your advice anyways and do it with a DialogFragment maybe that solves my problem.

Comment: @AlfonsoBriceño your actvity have implemted CalendarPickerFragment.OnDateReceiveCallBack interface right ?

Comment: @AdeelTurk Yes I get the date correctly on my fragment, the problem is I want to get that date and set it on the current running alert dialog.

Comment: of why dont you implement the listener on aler dialog and pass it to the Calednar Fragment .. let me make a sudo for you

Comment: @AlfonsoBriceño check my answer and let me know if it worked. I m pretty sure it should work

Comment: Simple? I look at it from the UX. You have a `Fragment` "FragmentInicio" that when you trigger `addDate()` you display an `AlertDialog` which appears to have the sole function of showing the user a date in the `EditText` "date_Text"  and allowing the user to change that date by opening another dialog "CalendarPickerFragment" from which the user can select a date, which is then returned to the `AlertDialog` and then what?  Bubble that date back up to "FragmentInicio"?  It appears to me that the `AlertDialog` has no significant roll in the UX except to disrupt the experience.

Comment: @Barns That's not the whole code obviously, I was just putting the essential code for finding the solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok so you can use the listener you have already craeted in your `alertDialog`
Following should be your `CalendarPickerFragment`

```
    public class CalendarPickerFragment extends DialogFragment implements  DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {

        private CalendarPickerFragment.OnDateReceiveCallBack mListener;
        private Context context;

        private static CalendarPickerFragment.OnDateReceiveCallBack mListenerForAlertDialog;

        public interface OnDateReceiveCallBack {
            public void onDateReceive(int dd, int mm, int yy);
        }

        public static CalendarPickerFragment getInstance(CalendarPickerFragment.OnDateReceiveCallBack callback) {
            mListenerForAlertDialog = callback;
            return new CalendarPickerFragment();
        }

        @Override
        public void onAttach(Context context) {
            super.onAttach(context);
            this.context = context;

            try {
                mListener = (CalendarPickerFragment.OnDateReceiveCallBack) context;
            } catch (ClassCastException e) {
                throw new ClassCastException(context.toString() + " must implement OnDateSetListener");
            }
        }

        public CalendarPickerFragment() {
        }


        @Override
        public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            final Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
            int year = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            int month = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            int day = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

            return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year, month, day);
        }

        @Override
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker datePicker, int i, int i1, int i2) {
            Log.d("tag", i + "/" + "/" + i1 + "/" + i2);
            mListener.onDateReceive(i, i1, i2);
            mListenerForAlertDialog.onDateReceive(i, i1, i2);
        }

    }
```

Now initialise this `fragmnet` as follows

```
CalendarPickerFragment newFragment =  CalendarPickerFragment.getInstance(new CalendarPickerFragment.OnDateReceiveCallBack() {
                @Override
                public void onDateReceive(int dd, int mm, int yy) {
                    // boom you wil get the call back on each date selection here
                    //eidtTextOfALertDialog.setText("whatEver")
                }
            });
            newFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "DatePicker");
```

Comment: HOLY MOLY! It works, thank you very much man. You are a genius.