# NullPoinerException in Fragment when handling dialog onclicklistener

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, dialog

I want to call a custom Dialog in fragment, where user will add some data and I want to get it in that fragment.

For this I created a dialog class and a special layout for it (I think it's not neccessary to post it here):

```
public class IntervalsDialog extends DialogFragment {
private TextView interval1, interval2, interval3, interval4;
private EditText weight1, weight2, weight3, weight4;

private IntervalDialogListener listener;



@Override
public void onAttach(@NonNull Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    try {
        listener = (IntervalDialogListener) context;
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        throw new ClassCastException(context.toString() + "you must implement IntervalsDialogListener");
    }
}

@NonNull
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

    LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_layout, null);
    builder.setView(view).setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    }).setPositiveButton("Go further", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            if (weight1.getText().toString().trim().matches("") || weight2.getText().toString().trim().matches("") ||
                    weight3.getText().toString().trim().matches("") || weight4.getText().toString().trim().matches("")){
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "You must fill in all the blanks to continue", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else{
                int w1 = Integer.valueOf(weight1.getText().toString().trim());
                int w2 = Integer.valueOf(weight2.getText().toString().trim());
                int w3 = Integer.valueOf(weight3.getText().toString().trim());
                int w4 = Integer.valueOf(weight4.getText().toString().trim());
                listener.onPositiveButtonClicked(w1, w2, w3, w4);
            }
        }
    });

    interval1 = view.findViewById(R.id.interval1);
    interval2 = view.findViewById(R.id.interval2);
    interval3 = view.findViewById(R.id.interval3);
    interval4 = view.findViewById(R.id.interval4);

    weight1 = view.findViewById(R.id.weight1);
    weight2 = view.findViewById(R.id.weight2);
    weight3 = view.findViewById(R.id.weight3);
    weight4 = view.findViewById(R.id.weight4);

    setIntervals();
    return builder.create();
}

public interface IntervalDialogListener{
    void onPositiveButtonClicked(int weigh1, int weight2, int weight3, int weight4);
}

private void setIntervals(){
    int dayStart = 360;
    int dayEnd = 1320;
    ArrayList<Interval> idealInt = new ArrayList<>();
    int dayInterval = (dayEnd - dayStart)/4;
    for (int i = dayStart; i < dayEnd; i+= dayInterval) {
        idealInt.add(new Interval(i, i + dayInterval));
    }
    interval1.setText(idealInt.get(0).toString());
    interval2.setText(idealInt.get(1).toString());
    interval3.setText(idealInt.get(2).toString());
    interval4.setText(idealInt.get(3).toString());
}
}
class Interval{
private int start, end;

Interval(int start, int end){
    this.start = start;
    this.end = end;
}
public String toString() {
    return (toTime(start) + " - " + toTime(end));
}
private static String toTime (int a) {
    String s = "";
    int b = a/60;
    int c = a%60;
    if (c < 10) {
        s =  b + " : " + 0 + c;
    }
    else {
        s =  b + " : " + c;
    }
    return s;
}
}
```

I faced a problem that my MainActivity could not be casted to a listener. I followed [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47740237/add-date-picker-fragment-inside-fragment) and sended data first to my MainActivity:

```
 @Override
public void onPositiveButtonClicked(int weigh1, int weight2, int weight3, int weight4) {
    AddDataFragment fragment = new AddDataFragment();
    fragment.getDataFromMainActivity(weigh1, weight2, weight3, weight4);
}
```

Then wrote a method for getting this data in my fragment (I hope, I did everything right up to this moment):

```
  public void getDataFromMainActivity(int weigh1, int weight2, int weight3, int weight4){
   Toast.makeText(getContext(), weigh1 + " -- " + weight2 + " -- " +  weight3 + " -- " +  weight4, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
   AddDataFragmentDirections.ActionSort action = AddDataFragmentDirections.actionSort();
   action.setCurrentDate(currentDateGot);
   action.setWeight1(weigh1);
   action.setWeight2(weight2);
   action.setWeight3(weight3);
   action.setWeight4(weight4);
   Navigation.findNavController(getView()).navigate(action);
  }
```

Then I simply want to check if the data is saved correctly via Toast message. And then I get this error:

```
 java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.content.Context.getPackageName()' on a null object reference
    at android.widget.Toast.<init>(Toast.java:114)
    at android.widget.Toast.makeText(Toast.java:277)
    at android.widget.Toast.makeText(Toast.java:267)
    at com.example.chronosaur.ui.AddDataFragment.getDataFromMainActivity(AddDataFragment.java:232)
    at com.example.chronosaur.ui.MainActivity.onPositiveButtonClicked(MainActivity.java:44)
    at com.example.chronosaur.ui.IntervalsDialog$1.onClick(IntervalsDialog.java:64)
    at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage(AlertController.java:166)
    ...
```

Why does this error occur? What did I miss? Please, help me. Thanks for any help.

Comment: When you call getDataFromMainActivity fragment does not attach to host Activity it means context is null.

Comment: And how can I attach it?

Comment: You using navigation component right it should be attach to nav host.

Comment: It's not a main fragment. There is one already attached (Home Fragment) and from home I navigate to this one.

Comment: Maybe I did something wrong with it... Could you please explain, how to attach it to NavHost? There is my NavHost fragment in MainActivity: `<fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragment"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/nav_graph1"
        android:layout_above="@+id/bottom_nav"/>`

Comment: I'm still a little confused

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `DialogFragment` was never attached to your activity. After instantiating your `AddDataFragment` use following way to attach it with your activity.

```
FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
fragment.show(fm, "tag");
```

**Ignore the following part if your minSdk is not below 23.**

`getContext()` is an API 23+ method which may produce exceptions on lower API devices.

Create a `Context` variable in your class to store the context.

```
...    
private Context context; //add this

@Override
public void onAttach(@NonNull Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    this.context = context; //add this
    ...
}
```

And replace `getContext()` with `context` e.g. `Toast` by using:

```
Toast.makeText(context, weigh1 + " -- " + weight2 + " -- " +  weight3 + " -- " +  weight4, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Comment: But my onAttach method is in a separate class IntervalsDialog and I'm calling Toast from a fragment. How do I access this `context`variable?

Comment: Yes, create that in your `IntervalsDialog` class just after you created the `listener` variable. Remember `onAttach` will be called when you will call `fragment.show(fm,"tag")` otherwise not.